# Can ammonia and sulfur dioxide oceans coexist?

Tags: science-based, alternate-worlds, ocean

I have a world that has a **0.2 bar** atmosphere and at **-65°C**, so theoretically, ammonia and sulfur dioxide can exist as a liquid in those conditions. What if an ocean of both liquids existed? Would it even be possible, or will the whole ocean just solidify into a crystal?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Ammonia is a strong reducing agent. Sulfur dioxide is an oxidizing agent. [They will spontaneously react even at cryogenic temperatures](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03086648008078204), forming a red solid of HNSO polymers. If there is excess sulfur dioxide, the same solid surface will catalyze its decomposition, producing solid sulfur and sulfates. If there is excess ammonia, you might be able to have an ocean of ammonia over the solid HNSO surface.